# Identifying message type from active MQ console

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

Is it possible to identify what message type was used by the producer, something like

```
session.createTextMessage(...)
```

by looking at the Active MQ console and opening a message in the  "Pending Messages" list?

I see Type, but that is left blank.

[image: Active MQ Console]

Answer (score 0):

The Type field on that page maps the JMSType in the JMS Message.  If you set the JMSType on your message for routing or other purposes it will be shown on that page.